oracle check if record exists before insert then if exist update
In oracle I would like to check if a record exists before insert then if exist update the record.
This site was really helpful. Is there a better method to do what I am trying to do? Why did the second method not work?
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-if-a-row-already-exists-in-plsql/
DECLARE
  v_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO v_count
  FROM employees
  WHERE employee_id = 100;

  IF v_count > 0 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Row exists in employees table for employee_id = 100');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Row does not exist in employees table for employee_id = 100');
  END IF;
END;

DECLARE
  v_exists BOOLEAN := FALSE;
BEGIN
  SELECT 'TRUE'
  INTO v_exists
  FROM dual
  WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM employees
    WHERE employee_id = 101
  );

  IF v_exists THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Row exists in employees table for employee_id = 101');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Row does not exist in employees table for employee_id = 101');
  END IF;
END;

Initial setup
CREATE TABLE people(
  id int primary key,
  name varchar(55),
  status int,
  phone varchar(55)
);

INSERT INTO people (id, name, status, phone) 
  WITH names AS (
    SELECT 1 id, 'jOHN' name, 1 status, '214-444-1234' phone     FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'John', 1, '214-444-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 3, 'Mary', 0, '555-111-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 4, 'Mary', 0, '555-111-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 5, 'Jeff', 0, '214-222-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 6, 'Jeff', 0, '214-222-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 7, 'Bill', 1, '817-333-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 8, 'Bill', 1, '817-333-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 9, 'Bob' , 1, '214-555-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 10, 'Bob' , 1, '214-555-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 11, 'Ruth',     1,      'Mrs'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 12, 'Isabelle', 2,      'Miss'   FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 13, 'Justin',   3,     'Master' FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 14, 'Lisa',     4,      'Dr'     FROM dual 
  ) 
  SELECT * FROM names;

This worked on my database.
DECLARE
    v_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
    -- Check if a row exists based on specific conditions
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO v_count
    FROM people
    WHERE id = 1;

    IF v_count > 0 THEN
        -- Row exists
        -- Perform necessary actions
        UPDATE people SET name = 'jack' WHERE id = 1;

    ELSE
        -- Row does not exist
        -- Perform necessary actions
        INSERT INTO people VALUES
        (1, 'Josh', 1, '214-444-1235');
    END IF;
END;

Surprisingly did not work on dbfiddle.
ORA-06550: line 21, column 3:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   ; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.

I was unable to make the second method work on my database or dbfiddle.
DECLARE
  v_exists BOOLEAN := FALSE;
BEGIN
  SELECT 'TRUE'
  INTO v_exists
  FROM dual
  WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM people
    WHERE id = 1
  );

  IF v_exists THEN
    UPDATE people SET name = 'jack' WHERE id = 1;
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO people VALUES
    (1, 'Josh', 1, '214-444-1235');
  END IF;
END;

This was my database error message.
[Error] Execution (71: 8): ORA-06550: line 5, column 8:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

This was dbfiddle error message.
ORA-06550: line 19, column 3:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   ; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.

https://dbfiddle.uk/b7z78r_u
edit
This was mentioned to me. I am looking for a beginner friendly answer with examples. I spent the time to provide an example and two attempts at an answer to the question. My first answer worked. My second answer did not work. I would also like to know why my second answer did not work. This can not be asked in someone else's post. I would also like to know if there is a better way to do what I am attempting to do.
The post in the comments does not have any beginner friendly answers with examples. Examples are very important for beginners. I went through the answers that I understood and they did not work. Most of those answers are to complicated for a beginner to understand. I did provide one working answer. Not sure why the second answer did not work. MT0 also provided a beginner friendly answer with an example. Looking for beginner friendly answers and examples.
How to UPSERT (update or insert into a table?)

This question is similar to: How to UPSERT (update or insert into a table?). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@KenWhite I went through the examples that I understood and they did not work. Most of those examples are to complicated for a beginner to understand. I did provide one working example. Not sure why the second example did not work. MT0 also provided a beginner friendly example. Looking for beginner friendly examples.

Use a MERGE statement so you can do everything in a single statement:
MERGE INTO people dst
USING (
  SELECT 1 AS id,
         'Jack' AS name,
         1 AS status,
         '214-444-1235' AS phone
  FROM   DUAL
) src
ON (src.id = dst.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET name = src.name
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (id, name, status, phone)
  VALUES (src.id, src.name, src.status, src.phone);

fiddle
If you use separate SELECT, INSERT and UPDATE statements then you need to process the source data-set row-by-row (in your case you only have a single row but you could also merge a larger data-set) and would need two statements (with context switches between PL/SQL and SQL between each) for each row - which is slow. MERGE is only a single statement for the entire source data-set - which will be much faster and generate less logs.

If you want to INSERT and UPDATE different values (although I'm not sure why you would want to do this) then:
MERGE INTO people dst
USING DUAL 
ON (dst.id = 1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET name = 'Jack'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (id, name, status, phone)
  VALUES (1, 'Josh', 1, '214-444-1235');



I was unable to make the second method work on my database or dbfiddle.

'TRUE' is a string literal, it is not a BOOLEAN so, if you try to assign a string to a non-string, you get the error PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type.
BOOLEAN is a PL/SQL data-type and is not supported in SQL statements so, if you want to fix your statement, use a data-type that is supported:
DECLARE
  v_exists VARCHAR2(5) := 'FALSE';
BEGIN
  SELECT 'TRUE'
  INTO v_exists
  FROM dual
  WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM people
    WHERE id = 1
  );

  IF v_exists = 'TRUE' THEN
    UPDATE people SET name = 'jack' WHERE id = 1;
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO people VALUES
    (1, 'Josh', 1, '214-444-1235');
  END IF;
END;
/


why is merge better? Do you know why my second example did not work?

This is the simplest method for row-by-row processing:
DECLARE
    v_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
    -- Check if a row exists based on specific conditions
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO v_count
    FROM people
    WHERE id = 1;

    IF v_count > 0 THEN
        -- Row exists
        -- Perform necessary actions
        UPDATE people SET name = 'jack' WHERE id = 1;

    ELSE
        -- Row does not exist
        -- Perform necessary actions
        INSERT INTO people VALUES
        (1, 'Josh', 1, '214-444-1235');
    END IF;
END;


For single row work, it is more straight-forward than MERGE which is designed for bulk processing many rows (datawarehouse-style).
The SELECT COUNT(*) technique avoids having to use an exception handler to routinely trap NO_DATA_FOUND, and as long as you are looking for a primary key should not involve more work than necessary to check for row existence.
The use of dual and subqueries not ideal because unnecessarily complex, and dual should be limited to only infrequent usage. Historically dual was just a normal table with one row in it, but SYS could insert a second row and blow up all your code that uses it. I think that may have changed over the years (haven't tried recently), but this memory haunts the use of dual.
Lastly, the IF THEN ELSE... logic of PL/SQL is easy to read and debug.

The problem with using MERGE in a single-row situation like this is that it is unnecessarily cumbersome, is harder to log and/or debug (did it try to do an update or an insert?), you can't (easily) get # of rows inserted vs. updated, and if you are driving from a variable or literal rather than another table, will require the use of dual which is inelegant. For these reasons, row-by-row processing is best done with normal SELECT - INSERT - UPDATE operations using PL/SQL conditional logic, whereas bulk warehouse-style processing that involves conditional or complex updates are best done with MERGE.

A simple way, if we're just talking about inserting or updating a single row:
BEGIN
  UPDATE people SET name = 'jack' WHERE id = 1;

  IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO people VALUES
        (1, 'Josh', 1, '214-444-1235');
  END IF;
END;

One drawback: if your database has many concurrent users and two (or more) users execute this code at the same time, then there could be a race condition where both users attempt to update, get zero rows, and then both attempt to insert (resulting either in duplicate rows or an duplicate key error).
In a highly concurrent environment, if you still want to be lazy about it, it's safer to switch the order of the insert and update:
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO people VALUES
        (1, 'Josh', 1, '214-444-1235');
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN dup_val_on_index THEN
      UPDATE people SET name = 'jack' WHERE id = 1;
  END;
END;

... assuming you have unique keys that prevent the same from from being inserted twice.
With a MERGE statement, as answered by MT0, you don't have to worry about any of this and it works for row sets greater than one row.  But I'll admit I still use the INSERT/UPDATE patterns above from time to time.
